# How to update wamp 2.5 to 3.0.6

Tags: server, updates, wampserver

I want to update my wamp server from 2.5 to 3.0.6 because I need PHP 5.6 or above for a project. But there are a lot of databases and projects on wamp 2.5, so I want to update it instead of uninstalling older version and install wamp 3.0

What is the simple and best way to achieve it??

Comment: Why would one want to install php-5.6 these days? php-7 has been released long ago, is here and stable...

Comment: Has any version of wamp server available with PHP7 ??

Comment: Sorry, I can't say. But then again I never understood why people use that distribution instead of simply installing the components it is composed of. Just a few clicks in the software management anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can upgrade WAMPServer 2.5 directly to WAMPServer 3.0.3 and from there to the latest version which is V3.0.9 (at the time or writing this answer). This version has PHP7.0 already installed in it, and many ADDON versions of PHP available if the version that comes with WAMPServer install is not the one you want including PHP7.1.

See the [backup repo for WAMPServer](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Download WAMPServer 3.0.3 which allows a direct upgrade from WAMPServer 2.5

Then upgrade WAMPServer to V3.0.9.

Then ADDON whichever version of PHP / Apache / MySQL / MariaDB that you want to use.

Then backup your databases, using your existing version of MYSQL.

Then switch to which ever version of MySQL you now want to use, and restore all your databases.

Comment: When I update to V3.0.9 then it shows 403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Where are you trying to acsess your site from? The PC running WAMPServer or another PC

Comment: PC running WAMPserver and I try to open localhost then above message shown.

Comment: Actually, localhost mapped to IP address 127.0.0.1

Comment: So have you checked the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file?

Comment: Thanks for the help, localhost running fine. But it shows PHP version: 5.6.25 on localhost page even after installing PHP 7.1.8 addon. Why??

Comment: You have to manually SWITCH to a newly installed version of PHP, or Apache or MySQL. See the wampmanager menu `wampmanager->PHP->version` and click on the version you want to use